# Unexpected token. A constructor, method, or property was expected

Tags: reactjs

Any hint or help would be greatly appreciated it.
I defined a function onFormSubmit but I cannot use the word "function" in front of onFormSubmit().
I get the following error:
Unexpected token. A constructor, method, or property was expected.

It seemed I have to use only "onFormSubmit() {}" without the word function.

SearchBar.js:

```
        import React from 'react';

    class SearchBar extends React.Component {

       state = { term: '' };

       function onFormSubmit(event)
       {

       }

       onFormSubmit(event)
       {

       }


        render() {
        return (
        <div className="ui segment">
            <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="ui form">
            <div className="field">
                <label>Image Search</label>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.term} onChange={(e) => this.setState({ term: e.target.value.toUpperCase()})} />
            </div>
            </form>

        </div>);
        }
    }

    export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes that's correct inside a class you don't declare your methods with `function`

you can declare like that:

```
   onFormSubmit(event){}
```

but I recommend like an arrow function, which auto binds your `this` component context:

```
onFormSubmit = (event) => {}
```